# Are there any way to send script value into protected override void OnActionExecuted in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to send radio button value to controller `protected override void OnActionExecuted` which is inside `_Layout`.

Can anyone please suggest me how can I do this?

_Layout

```
<div class="NorthSouthHemisphere">
      @Html.RadioButton("NorthernSouthernHemisphere", "NH")Northern
      @Html.RadioButton("NorthernSouthernHemisphere", "SH")Southern
  </div>
```

Controller

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (User != null)
            {
                var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var username = User.Identity.Name;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
                {
                    var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
                   var Account = context.Account.SingleOrDefault(u => u.AccountId == user.AccountID);
                    var Country = context.Country.SingleOrDefault(u => u.CountryId == user.CountryID);
                    string fullName = string.Concat(new string[] { user.FirstName, " ", user.LastName });

                }
            }
            Hemishpere();
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
```

Script

```
 $(document).on('change', '.NorthSouthHemisphere input[type = "radio"]', function () {
                 var selectedVal = "";
                var selected = $(".NorthSouthHemisphere input[type='radio']:checked");
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    selectedVal = selected.val();

                }
            })
```

Comment: What is it that your trying to do here. What is the purpose of your `ActionFilter`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, basically, I want to send radio button value into this as this is the base controller. So when I change radio button, I want to get that value here .As this controller method is going to execute everytime if I go another page also. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, you are not really making sense. Why are you using an `ActionFilter`? And what does it do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, sorry Stephen. No idea what it does. It was already there before. I only want to implement these radio button here. Please guide me.

Comment: How can I do that? - I do not know what you are wanting to do or why

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry for that. I will explain my requirements. Currently, I am displaying ads based on user's visiting country and for that reason I have place `Hemisphere()` method here. Now I wan to add radio buttons in layout. If user clicks on any of these radio buttons, only that respective ads should display.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, may be I am doing it in wrong way. My focus is to get that value and store it in session so that on each radio click, it displays the ads accordingly.

Comment: Then you would make an ajax call to a method that saves the selected option to your database (not `Session`, but you could also add it to `Session`), and if you also want to update the ads in the current page, you would return a response to update that part of the page in the `success` callback.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please guide me to write `Ajax` call here. I am getting lost here. Please help me.

Comment: You have not given enough context for me to do that (but you already know how to make an ajax call)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, can you please invite me for chat. Always appreciated your kind help.

Comment: Use your [previous chat session](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177853/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mvc)